# Hibernate no se guardan sus relaciones

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de guardar un objeto con hibernate que tiene relaciones con otros objetos. Cuando recupero el objeto guardado, sus relaciones aparecen vacías.

**MatchModel**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "matches")
public class MatchModel extends Identificable {
  private static String modelName = "MatchModel";
  private static String tableName = "matches";

  @OneToOne
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
  private TeamModel local;

  @OneToOne
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
  private TeamModel visitor;

  @Column(name = "result")
  private String result;

  @Column(name = "week")
  private String week;

  @Column(name = "year")
  private String year;

  //Gets and setters
}
```

**TeamModel**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teams")
public class TeamModel extends Identificable {

  private static String modelName = "TeamModel";

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
  private List<PlayerModel> players = new ArrayList<>();
  @OneToMany(
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
  private List<MatchModel> matches = new ArrayList<>();

//Gets and setters
}
```

En este metodo **Controller** es donde se empieza el proceso de guardado del "matchModel"

```
public static boolean addMatch(TeamModel local, TeamModel visitor, String result, String week, String season) {
    MatchModel match = new MatchModel(local, visitor, result, week, season);

    if (MatchDao.getInstance().exist(match)) {
        DialogsUtil.errorMessage("Ya existe un partido con los mismos valores");
        return false;
    } else {
        try {
            local.getMatches().add(match);
            visitor.getMatches().add(match);

            MatchDao.getInstance().add(match);

            System.out.println("test");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**AbstractDao**

```
public abstract class AbstractDao<T extends Identificable> {
  protected Session session = null;
  protected Transaction tx = null;

  protected void startOperation() throws HibernateException {
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
  }

 public List<T> getAll(String modelName) {
    Query query = executeQuery("from " + modelName);
    List<T> objects = query == null ? new ArrayList<T>() : query.list();
    return objects;
 }

  public void add(T obj) {
    try {
        startOperation();

        session.save(obj);
        tx.commit();

    } catch (
            HibernateException he) {
        handleException(he);
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        throw he;
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

**HibernateUtil** donde esta la session factory

```
public class HibernateUtil {
 private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
 static {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure(new File("hibernate.cfg.xml"))
                .buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

  public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
  }
```

[image: El objeto que se guarda]
[image: La lista que se recupera]

**Actualizo con datos de la base de datos**

Tabla teams
[image: Estado tabla teams]

Tabla matches
[image: Estado tabla matches]

Tabla intermedia
[image: Estado tabla intermedia]

Comment: Falta que añadas las tablas referenciadas (SQL) para comprobar que el *mapeo* es correcto

Comment: Las tablas las crea automaticamente hibernate ya que tengo puesta la propiedad `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>`

Comment: Al obtener el objeto tienes null, pero si miras las tablas ¿Están creadas las entradas? Es para saber si el problema es al crear o al leer

Comment: Vale @pablo-lozano, estoy revisando los registros en las tablas directamente con el mysql workbench y veo que en la tabla `matches` se crea el registro, pero en la tabla intermedia que crea hibernate `teams_matches` no hay ningun registro. Por eso se recuperaran null. Así que debe de ser error a la hora de insertar.

Comment: ¿Las relaciones no deberían ser @OneToMany y @ManyToMany? Te preguntaba por las tablas por esto, tal y como están definidas me daba la impresión de que no había tabla intermedia

Comment: Vale, tenias razon. Ha sido cambiar en `MatchModel` los `OneToOne` a `ManyToOne` y ya funciona. Cagada mia. Pon la respuesta y te la acepto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás usando la anotación @OneToOne, que indica a Hibernate que la relación es uno a uno y no necesita tabla intermedia. Deberías tener algo así:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "matches")
public class MatchModel extends Identificable {
  private static String modelName = "MatchModel";
  private static String tableName = "matches";

  @ManyToOne
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
  private TeamModel local;

  @ManyToOne
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
  private TeamModel visitor;

  ...
```